# Mongodb, golang. Can i count an slice/map without loading data into memory?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

In my collection labs I have:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e602ada35ea4db6e4eee27"),
    "areas" : [
        "nanotech",
        "robotics"
    ]
}
```

My query is:
`db.labs.find({"_id" : ObjectId("57e602ada35ea4db6e4eee27")},{areas:1})`

What I want is to count the elements in the slice but not retrieve the whole slice, anyone know? I'm using the mgo package, which has a great correspondence with golang. Thanks

Comment: exactly, well I would just range through and increment a counter, but this loads the whole slice into memory, very inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
db.labs.aggregate([
  {$match: {"_id" : ObjectId("57e602ada35ea4db6e4eee27")}},
  {$project: {
      areasCount: {"$size": "$areas"}
    }
  }
])
```